# Reporte Excel como Calendar

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, phpspreadsheet, reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo una tabla donde muestro algunas tareas con una fecha asociada, mi objetivo es crear un reporte excel en forma de calendario donde se muestren las tareas correspondientes en cada dia del calendario

estoy usando Laravel y Spreadsheet

---

mi idea ha sido la siguiente, obtener las semanas la cantidad de semanas q trae un mes, y que dia de la semana corresponde a la fecha obtenida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui mi idea es segun las fechas q voy obteniendo ir pintando en el reporte

[image: idea]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en cuestión? Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Aqui muestro una imagen de la tabla con los datos [![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwzf5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwzf5.jpg) Deseo hacer un reporte PDF o EXCEL como un calendario, donde me muestre la descripción de la tarea en la fecha que le corresponda [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhS82.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhS82.png)

Comment: De nuevo: pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. No olvides además que el código debe ir siempre _como texto, con formato_. Usar capturas de pantalla [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976): no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Recuerda acceder a los enlaces proporcionados, y elimina tus _no-respuestas_.